# How to periodically execute a PHP script/plugin on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to update a database that I have stored localy based on an online API. I need to make API calls periodically. What is a good strategy when it comes to periodical PHP script execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cron job. There are tons of tutorials out there on how to do that. There is even a Wordpress Cron Job scheduler plugin (this link is only for reference, I'm not endorsing it specifically). You can find it [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/). Note that you will need administrative rights on the server to execute cron jobs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are administrative rights a hard thing to get with  common hosting plans available? Do you have any suggestions of hosting services?

Comment: No, that should be easy. Even on shared hosting you should at least have some limited ability to run a cron job. Personally I use Digital Ocean for hosting. They are Virtual Private Servers (VPS) that give you full control over the operating system. Lots of hosting companies do that though, it's just my preference.

Comment: Also, if my answer is sufficient, please mark it as Solved. Thanks!

Comment: Almost all hosting providers provide access to cronjobs. If you don't see it, reach out to the host. It's a pretty common feature.